# How to adapt a confirmation button of a dialog box to the button of a form

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I would use a dialog box in my form. I can display the dialog box in the form. I would like when I click on the "Yes" button in the dialog box that I can have the same behavior as the "Backward" button on my form. How do you do that? Thank you for your help. Below the code I developed:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="jquery-ui-1.10.4/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>

            <title>Test</title>
    <script>
    let validation = function(form) {

      $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
          Yes: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            document.getElementById("myForm-previous").submit();
          },
          No: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        }
      });

      return false;

    }
    </script>
        </head>

        <body>


        <div id="dialog" title="Confirmation">
    <p>Warning!!!
    You will lose your data!
    Do you want to continue ?</p>
        </div>
    <form id="myForm" name="myFrom"/>
            <input type="file"/><br/>
            <input type="file"/><br/>
            <input id="myForm-previous" value="BackWard" type="submit" onclick="return validation()"/><br/>
            <input id="myForm-next" value="Forward" type="submit"/>

    </form>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an error here:

```
   document.getElementById("myForm-previous").submit();
```

if you want to submit form, use FORM identificator, not BUTTON:

```
   document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```